# Animating button causing the button not to work

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I've decided to try to animate a button only when some details are not filled out. However, when the button is animating, it becomes inoperable. Can someone explain why this happens?

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    EnterDet.alpha = 1
    animateText()
}

func animateText(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.EnterDet.alpha = 1
    }, completion:  {
        (Comnpleted : Bool) -> Void in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
        self.EnterDet.alpha = 0.1

        }, completion: {
            (Completed : Bool) -> Void in
            self.animateText()
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Look at the list of options available for `UIViewAnimationOptions` and you will see an obvious solution.

Comment: Use animation with option block....And pass User Interaction Enable in the option